# Create logical vector from table in R

Tags: r

I'm looking at the data set pre-loaded into R called UCBAdmissions:

```
> str(UCBAdmissions)
table [1:2, 1:2, 1:6] 512 313 89 19 353 207 17 8 120 205 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
..$ Admit : chr [1:2] "Admitted" "Rejected"
..$ Gender: chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
..$ Dept  : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

I'd like to create a logical vector of every female where TRUE equates to "Admitted" and FALSE to "Rejected." How do I do that?

Second somewhat related question -- if I wanted to make matrix out of a vector, what would the notation for that be? For lists and data.frame I can use data$variable.I.wish.to.extract.

Jen

Comment: How many rows do you want in the matrix?

Comment: `logical.vector <- with(UCBAdmissions, Gender == 'Female' & Admit == 'Admitted')` for the second part, `matrix[ , 'variable.I.wish.to.extract', drop = FALSE]`

Comment: `as.matrix(my.vector)`

Comment: @rawr `UCBAdmissions` is a table - bit like an array - and `with` does't work on that structure.

Comment: I think you need to give use more context as to what you want. I've added an answer which goes part way but I don't think it is what you want. Can you take a look and then edit your question with a clearer description of what you want? As for the second question `data$variable.I.wish.to.extract` doesn't make a vector out of a matrix, so again, can you clarify what you want?

Comment: @GavinSimpson whoops, I read data frame. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

### This is *incomplete* but was too long to add as a comment. I will delete this or update it should the OP clarify what they want to achieve

---

For the first question, convert the `UCBAdmissions` object, which is a `"table"` object to a data frame, and then create a logical:

```
UCB <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
ind <- with(UCB, Gender == "Female" & Admit == "Admitted")
```

which gives

```
R> ind
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I suspect this *isn't what you want though, as the data are stored in contingency table format; there are only aggregated counts in the various classes. What `ind` is indexing is which rows of `UCB` where `Gender == "Female"` and `Admit = "Admitted"`. You'd get the same number of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values if you asked for `Gender == "Female"` and `Admit = "Rejected"`, just in a different order.

If you want to blow that out to actual data, you need to repeat the rows of `UCB`

```
R> head(UCB)
     Admit Gender Dept Freq
1 Admitted   Male    A  512
2 Rejected   Male    A  313
3 Admitted Female    A   89
4 Rejected Female    A   19
5 Admitted   Male    B  353
6 Rejected   Male    B  207
```

`Freq` times for each row, and then create the logical vector. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If the "with" command isn't working for you, you can also try the following to create your logical vector:

```
logical.vector <- ifelse(UCBAdmissions$Gender == "Female" & UCBAdmissions$Admit == "Admitted", TRUE, FALSE)
```

However, this logical vector includes males, meaning that you will get a false for all males in addition to females who were not admitted.

If you want a logical vector that truly returns FALSE only when it is a female who was not admitted, and TRUE when it is a female was was admitted, you will have to first subset the data like so:

```
females <- subset(UCBAdmissions, Gender == FEMALE)
logical.vector <- ifelse(females$Admit == "Admitted", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Hope this helps clarify a bit!